# Programming riddle - how to create file named "--help"

Tags: bash, terminal

Some time ago my friend asked me to create file named "--help" in Bash. Do you have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: `touch ./--help` or `> ./--help`, to remove it see `rm --help`

Answer (score 3):

Ideas from top of my head:

```
: > --help
: >> --help
touch -- --help
dd if=/dev/zero of=--help bs=1 count=1
truncate --size 0 -- --help
```